# Telegram Bot, placeholder for send documents?

Tags: curl, telegram

Good day,

Is there a chance to get placeholders for files working for telegram bots?
Scenario: I have a surveillance camera in front of my house, which is moving the latest shots into a specific folder. So basically there is a given folder with just one file in it, but the thing is that this file has a dynamic name including time of day and so on, and I want to keep that.

My current script is looking like this:

```
 curl -F chat_id="myChatID" -F document=@"file.jpg" https://api.telegram.org/botID/sendDocument
```

So this works pretty well, but I don't get it to work that the script send the whole content of a specific folder.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean sending all files in the folder altogether or one after another?

Comment: there will just be one file in that folder, but that file will have different names from time to time. Example... 20181024111940.jpg -> Year/Month/Day/HH/MM/SS

Answer (score 0):

what you need is just utilizing "ls" command like so:

```
curl -F chat_id="myChatID" -F document=@"$(ls -1)" https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/sendDocument
```

Comment: unfortunately gives me:
curl: (26) couldn't open file "$(ls -1)"

Comment: could you echo the result and see what happens? 
first command: OUTPUT="$(ls -1)" .....  and then this command:
echo "${OUTPUT}"